Is it possible to reference selector from isolated css file from code-behind of razor component of blazor web app?
I currently have binded the class attribute of a html element to a property in my code behind, of which i have assigned a string literal to the property. The string literal is then changed whenever i would like to change the style of my html element.
May i know if it's possible to reference a css selector from my isolated css file from my code-behind?
